# mvc 3 / igoogle / personal widgets / jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've been hunting around for some recomendations for building some customisable widgets for a project I'm working on. It's basically a dashboard for users. This is a common requirement, but I'd like it be customisable like the bbc.co.uk homepage. Users can close / edit or minimise the blocks.

I've seen things like dropthings and a few other examples, but I'm looking for something for MVC3, using JQUERY and as simple and staight forward an implementation as possible (read = I'm not an advanced coder!).

Any updated information would be great.

Thanks for your help fellow devs.

Phil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to license a commercial libary, ExtJS has a set of built in widgets that handles this very nicely. Here's the demo link:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/portal/portal.html

I've been looking for a free alternative for a project of my own, and I haven't found one that strikes me as suitably robust and well maintained. Which is why commercial alternatives exist, of course. There's nothing I've seen that's built into MVC3, but it should be easy to do so.

This post:

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/saving-state-for-collapsible-drag-drop-panels/

Shows how to do drag and drop panels with JQuery that are collapsible and have some database state saving. I've modified this in other projects to work with MVC 3, and it works quite well with minimal code.

Comment: looks interesting; the blog post is probably the way I'll go, it doesn't need to be too heavy and this seems to fit the bill. I'm surprised there isn't something out there already to do it (non-commercially that is).

Comment: Keeping something as complex as this up to date with changing browsers is a bit of a challenge. The blog post approach is simple enough that it should hold up, but once you've built the entire portal framework it's a bigger maintenance burden. The handful of JQuery plugins I looked at were all either abandoned, had performance issues, or both.

Comment: agreed, I've not found anything which solves this directly yet.